# Angular 4 | Looping Though Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

I have a multi-dimensional array with two keys, it looks like so.

```
user: any = {};
// index is from a for loop to add to the user (this part works perfectly)
this.user[index++] = {
   Name: name,
   Age: age,
}
```

However my issue is I'd like to loop through that in my angular HTML template using *ngFor, however I receive a error saying it doesn't support it. So my question is, how can I loop through this user array and print out both name and age value of each key inside of the array?

**My Attempt:**

```
 <li *ngFor="let user of users">{{user.Name}} - {{user.Age}}</li>
```

**The Error I Receive**:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

Thank you.

Comment: `user: any = {};` is not an array!. try `user: any = [];`

Comment: ^ He is not trying to access object key -values, just the declaration is wrong. `user: any[] = []` should fix it right?

Comment: @MohamedAbbas Agh, you're right. There goes an hour of my life trying to fix this issue. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Nicster15 Your're welcome :) , i convert my comment to answer. Check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user: any = {};` is not an array!. try `user: any = [];`

`let o = {};`  this is an object.
`let arr = [];`  this is an array.